# SQL Anywhere Parse 'varying' substring(s) into new columns

Tags: sql, regex, parsing, sqlanywhere

I have a DB column that consists of one long string. This string is made up of a number of sub-strings separated by CHAR(13). My issue is the sub-strings are varying in length. 
My goal is to parse out each sub-string (the piece between each CHAR(13)) and put this sub-string into it's own column.

The sub-strings are 'standardized' to a point example:

```
Voltage (VAC)=%CHAR(13)
Rating (A)=%CHAR(13)
Input Rating (A)=%CHAR(13)
```

-The (%) is varying in length. And the first line does not begin with CHAR(13).

I imagine I'll have to use a similar work-around but am unsure how to implement.
[Why we can't execute stored procedure in select statement in oracle? is there any strong reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562024/why-we-cant-execute-stored-procedure-in-select-statement-in-oracle-is-there-an)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use Sybase SQL Anywhere? If so, why you tagged MySql as well?

Comment: Yes I am using SQL Anywhere.  -Fixed

Comment: Do the answers here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828567/splitting-value-of-a-varchar-column-into-two-columns

Comment: @ The TTG Guy Thank you, this should be a good start!

Comment: @TTG Guy - my issue now is that I have more than just two Char(13) separating more than two sub strings.  I can find the first two sub-strings but not the subsequent sub-strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For specific columns:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(REGEX_SUBSTR(col1, 'Voltage \(VAC\)=[^\r]*'), 15) AS Voltage,
    SUBSTR(REGEX_SUBSTR(col1, 'Rating \(A\)=[^\r]*'), 12) AS Rating,
    SUBSTR(REGEX_SUBSTR(col1, 'Input Rating \(A\)=[^\r]*'), 18) AS Input_Rating
FROM mytable
```

For generic columns:

```
SELECT
    REGEX_SUBSTR(REGEX_SUBSTR(col1, '[^=\r]+=[^\r]*', 1, row_num), '^[^=]*') AS Name,
    SUBSTR(REGEX_SUBSTR(REGEX_SUBSTR(col1, '[^=\r]+=[^\r]*', 1, row_num), '=.*'), 2) AS Value
FROM mytable, sa_rowgenerator(1, 100)
WHERE REGEX_SUBSTR(col1, '[^=\r]+=[^\r]*', 1, row_num) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @Marcus Jarderot    Worked - Thank you very much!