# How can I return dataset in procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11gr2, sys-refcursor

I have a procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RIC.TEST 
(P_VAR1 IN VARCHAR2, P_VAR2 IN VARCHAR2, P_VAR3 IN VARCHAR2, P_VAR4 IN VARCHAR2)
IS 
L_RC SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO RIC.TEMP_TABLE
    SELECT * FROM RIC.TABLE WHERE COL1=P_VAR1 AND COL2=P_VAR2 AND COL3=P_VAR3 AND COL4=P_VAR4 AND ...;

OPEN L_RC
FOR 'SELECT .... FROM RIC.TEMP_TABLE WHERE ...';
...
```

TEMP_TABLE is a temporary table. I need to return and show second select output (SELECT .... FROM RIC.TEMP_TABLE WHERE ...) when I run this procedure. How can I do that? Is cursor wrong way for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: 11.2.0.4.0 - 2 node rac.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the procedure to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ric.test (p_var1     IN     VARCHAR2,
                                      p_var2     IN     VARCHAR2,
                                      p_var3     IN     VARCHAR2,
                                      p_var4     IN     VARCHAR2,
                                      p_cursor      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ric.temp_table
      SELECT *
        FROM ric.table
       WHERE col1 = p_var1 AND col2 = p_var2 AND col3 = p_var3;

   OPEN p_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM ric.temp_table;
END;
/
```

and execute the procedure as

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;
EXEC test (:cur);
PRINT cur;
```

If you would like to execute the procedure using SQL, wrap the procedure in a function which should be followed by calling the function in a SQL statement.
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17562883/599528)